# PSD to HTML/CSS slicing specifics for iPad and iPhone

Tags: iphone, html, css, ipad, slice

I have several PSD files designed for iPad and iPhone that I need to convert them to HTML/CSS. Compared with ordinary designes for computers, what kind of specific requirements does slicing for iPad and for iPhone have? Please list them if there are any. (I guess there is nothing special!)

Comment: Slicing is an old technique, used in the dark ages of table layouts. Today we use better techniques, (generally, we just use layers).

Comment: This is really something new to me. I thought that CSS div based slicing is what the professionals do. Can you provide some links for me that I had a better idea what about you are talking?

Comment: Well, in the previous age, we used to think "Where will this content go?" whether it's in the top, the bottom, the center or w/e. Today, we ask ourselves, "What does this content **mean**?" or "Where would it make the most sense to put it?". That said, we instead of laying the page out according to the mockup, we rely more on what content will inhabit each of the pieces. I can recommend the following: http://www.1stwebdesigner.com/freebies/psd-htmlcss-conversion-tutorials/ but it's really something you learn and experience for yourself.